# $\frac{1}{n} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii} \right)^2 \le \|(a_{i,j})\|^2_F$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

I want to show that one can estimate the Trace of a matrix by the Frobenius norm of a matrix. $$ \frac{1}{n}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii} \right)^2 \le  \|(a_{i,j})\|^2_F.$$

Unfortunately, I think that I just don't see how this can be done.

Comment: How about $(a_{i,j}) = I_n$? The left side then becomes $n^2$, the right side is $1$.

Comment: whoops, had the $\frac{1}{n}$ on the wrong side.

Answer (score 3):

$\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^T)$ is an inner product and induces the Frobenius norm.  Apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Neater than my answer.

Comment: @echo : Thanks.  I think it's the same proof in different clothes, really.

Comment: @echo : Maybe that's too strong.  Same circle of ideas, at least.

Answer (score 2):

I first prove the following inequality:
$$
(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii})^2 \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}^2 \tag{1}
$$
*proof*: Let $X$ be a random variable with values $\{a_{11}, a_{22}, \cdots, a_{nn}\}$, each with probability $\frac{1}{n}$. Then
$$
E[X] =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}\\
E[X^2] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}^2
$$
By Jensen's inequality,
$$
E[X^2] \geq E[X]^2
$$
Q.E.D

---

Now, everything is easy. According to (1), we have
$$
\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii})^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}^2 \tag{2}
$$
Moreover, we have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^na_{ii}^2 \leq \|(a_{i,j})\|_F^2 \tag{3}
$$
according to the definition of Frobenius norm.

From (2),(3), we've proved the inequality in question.